# How to create a new variable based on one condition (is.na) at the minimum of another variable in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to create a new variable (`obs.new`) that conserves the original value from `obs` except when the minimum of `date` is missing. In those cases, the `obs.new` value should be the `mean.obs` value. The other instances where `obs` is `na`, should remain `na`.

This is a reproducible example of what I did:

```
library(dplyr)

data.1 <-read.csv(text = "
site ,treat,date,obs,mean.obs,
1,a,33,0.585581765,0.4,
1,a,34,0.871886986,0.4,
1,a,35,,0.4,
1,a,36,,0.4,
1,a,37,,0.4,
1,a,38,,0.4,
1,a,39,0.628236902,0.4,
1,a,40,0.041956742,0.4,
1,b,36,,0.52,
1,b,37,0.327067686,0.52,
1,b,38,,0.52,
1,b,39,,0.52,
1,b,40,,0.52,
1,b,41,0.982637394,0.52,
1,b,42,0.80141212,0.52,
1,b,43,0.739522519,0.52,
2,a,56,,0.48,
2,a,57,0.724849037,0.48,
2,a,58,0.050617254,0.48,
2,a,59,,0.48,
2,a,60,,0.48,
2,a,61,,0.48,
2,a,62,,0.48,
2,a,63,0.269993451,0.48,
2,b,23,0.216291392,0.49,
2,b,24,,0.49,
2,b,25,,0.49,
2,b,26,,0.49,
2,b,27,,0.49,
2,b,28,,0.49,
2,b,29,0.951644067,0.49,
2,b,30,0.745131113,0.49")


data.1.1 <- data.1 %>%
  group(site, treat) %>%
  mutate(obs.new = if_else(is.na(slice(which.min(date))),
                           mean.obs, obs))
```

This is the error I got:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `obs.new`.
x no applicable method for 'slice' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
i Input `obs.new` is `if_else(is.na(slice(which.min(date))), mean.obs, obs)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: site = 1, treat = "a".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The expected result is this:

[image]

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Where is `dap` in your data

Comment: My bad. I corrected the question. There is no ```dap```. I meant ```date```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `obs` value if `obs` is `NA` and `date` is minimum date in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

data.1 %>%
  group_by(site, treat) %>%
  mutate(mean.obs.new = ifelse(is.na(obs) & date == min(date), mean.obs, obs))

#    site treat  date     obs mean.obs mean.obs.new
#   <int> <chr> <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     1 a        33  0.586      0.4        0.586 
# 2     1 a        34  0.872      0.4        0.872 
# 3     1 a        35 NA          0.4       NA     
# 4     1 a        36 NA          0.4       NA     
# 5     1 a        37 NA          0.4       NA     
# 6     1 a        38 NA          0.4       NA     
# 7     1 a        39  0.628      0.4        0.628 
# 8     1 a        40  0.0420     0.4        0.0420
# 9     1 b        36 NA          0.52       0.52  
#10     1 b        37  0.327      0.52       0.327 
# … with 22 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.1 %>%
  group_by(site, treat) %>%
  mutate(obs.new = if_else(!is.na(obs), 
                           obs,
                           if_else(date == min(date), 
                                   mean.obs,
                                   0)
                           )
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

change group to group_by
then you can use case_when()

```
library(dplyr)
data.1 %>%
  group_by(site, treat) %>%
  mutate(obs.new = case_when(!is.na(obs) ~ obs,
                             date==min(date) ~ mean.obs,
                             TRUE ~ 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.1 %>%
    group_by(site, treat) %>%
    mutate(obs.new = coalesce(obs, 
        if_else(row_number() == 1, mean.obs, NA_real_))) %>%
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 32 x 7
    site treat  date     obs mean.obs X     obs.new
   <int> <chr> <int>   <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>   <dbl>
 1     1 a        33  0.586      0.4  NA     0.586 
 2     1 a        34  0.872      0.4  NA     0.872 
 3     1 a        35 NA          0.4  NA    NA     
 4     1 a        36 NA          0.4  NA    NA     
 5     1 a        37 NA          0.4  NA    NA     
 6     1 a        38 NA          0.4  NA    NA     
 7     1 a        39  0.628      0.4  NA     0.628 
 8     1 a        40  0.0420     0.4  NA     0.0420
 9     1 b        36 NA          0.52 NA     0.52  
10     1 b        37  0.327      0.52 NA     0.327 
# … with 22 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data.1)[, mean.obs.new := fifelse(is.na(obs) & date == min(date), mean.obs, obs), .(site, treat)]
```